# about python nfcpy"couldn't find any usable nfc reader"

Tags: nfc

I am a beginner.After install libUSB,Python and PyUSB package,and my ACR122U is connected to the computer.Then I want to achieve the code as follows:

```
import os
import sys
import time

sys.path.insert(1, os.path.split(sys.path[0])[0])

import nfc
import nfc.ndef

def main():
    clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend()

    print "Please touch a tag to send a hello to the world"
    while True:
        tag = clf.poll()
        if tag and tag.ndef:
            break

    text_en = nfc.ndef.TextRecord(language="en", text="Hello World")
    text_de = nfc.ndef.TextRecord(language="de", text="Hallo Welt")
    text_fr = nfc.ndef.TextRecord(language="fr", text="Bonjour tout le monde")
    message = nfc.ndef.Message( [text_en, text_de, text_fr] )

    tag.ndef.message = str(message)

    print "Remove this tag"
    while tag.is_present:
        time.sleep(1)

    print "Now touch it again to receive a hello from the world"
    while True:
        tag = clf.poll()
        if tag and tag.ndef:
            break

    message = nfc.ndef.Message( tag.ndef.message )
    for record in message:
        if record.type == "urn:nfc:wkt:T":
            text = nfc.ndef.TextRecord( record )
            print text.language + ": " + text.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I  get to the line

```
clf= nfc.ContactlessFrontend()"
```

then came the question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "D:\tools\python\nfc\clf.py", line 58, in __init__
raise LookupError("couldn't find any usable nfc reader")
LookupError: couldn't find any usable nfc reader
```

I dont know how to solve it .Can anybody help me ?

Comment: did you try setting your python log level to debug and running again? there are a lot of log messages emitted from the module that could be helpful in determining what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

I did as "Petesh" said in his comment by running

```
python -d helloworld.py
```

In the output there was

```
Exception usb.USBError: 'error submitting URB: Operation not permitted'
```

After runnung the same command with "sudo", it worked.